# Raspbian Jessie Lite Boot Delay - Long Wait for DHCPCD

Tags: networking, boot, pi-zero, jessie-lite

I just downloaded and installed Raspbian Jessie Lite v2016-02-09 on my Raspberry Pi Zero. The DHCPCD process slows boot time by ~40 seconds. I do not plan to connect to the internet using my Pi. How can I disable DHCPCD / networking?

```
[...] A start job is running for dhcpcd on all interfaces (38sec / 1min 38sec)
```

I [tried setting up a static IP address](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=101892&p=705852), but nothing changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd.service` should stop `dhcpcd`.

It is also possible to set Raspbian to not wait for the network on boot (see `raspi-config`).

Comment: raspi-config does not work !
it is /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd5 that starts dhcpd networking it seems a bug in upgrade

Comment: This works, but then the eth0 interface is disabled. Tested on the latest raspbian-jessie-lite. Would appreciate the solution that does not disable the eth0. I suspect there is a bug somewhere in startup scripts? Strangely enough, wlan0 (on raspberry 3) is unaffected.

Comment: @xmp125a If you have a question ask it - not as a comment on an answer.

Comment: I have the same problem. sometimes eth0 comes up, sometimes I get this delay waiting for dhcpd, and then eth0 never comes up, and  as it is headless I can't get to it. Cheap hack I added ifup eth0 to /etc/rc.local and that forces the issue, but it would be nice to know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling helped me much better. Even as the service was stopped after reboot my Pi kept performing the job. Hence,

```
 sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd.service
```

did the trick for me.